# How to install a LaTeX package in Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive

I am trying to install Acrotex to use eforms.

I am running on Ubuntu.

I did

```
sudo -i tlmgr update --list
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

So I tried to remove everything then

```
apt-get remove 'texlive-*'
apt-get install texlive
```

Unfortunately, it seems to install texlive 2019, not the 2021 :(

```
$ tlmgr --version
tlmgr revision 53568 (2020-01-27 19:20:16 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2019


$ tlmgr --verify-repo=none install acrotex
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2021).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I even tried

```
$ wget https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
$ sudo ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

How can I install a package with TeX Live?

Comment: The TeX live you can install via `apt`/`apt-get` (or other Linux package managers) is usually frozen (often in a state that can no longer be considered current). The `tlmgr` that ships with those TeX live versions should generally not be used to install or updated packages. Packages should only be installed via the Linux package manager. If you want a current TeX live with working `tlmgr`, install "vanilla" TeX live from TUG.org: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864

Comment: you need to decide if you want the system texlive installed via apt (which is usually a year or two behind, depending on your linux distribution) or install the upstream texlive from tug using tlmgr (which gives you the latest but doesn't tell apt that you have tex installed so you need to manage the dependenciies on other apt packages that need tex)   if you install via apt update it using apt not via tlmgr

Comment: That said, the specific package you are looking for (`acrotex`) is not included in TeX live because it only works with the non-free Acrobat Reader. You have to install it manually. See the bundle documentation http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex/doc/aeb_man.pdf

Comment: @moewe I also tried to install acrotex manually by downloading the zip from ctan and placing it into `/usr/local/share/texmf` then I ran `sudo texhash`. Unfortunately I still get the issue `eforms.sty not found`.

Comment: The files must be placed in the correct subdirectory of a TDS tree. So that'd be `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex` or some such

Comment: See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-tds, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-install-where and https://texfaq.org/FAQ-what-TDS

Answer (score 1):

This example is with the package [`acrotex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acrotex) with TeX Live and Ubuntu.

Create the path `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/` end extract the package [`acrotex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acrotex) to this path. Then run the following commands wtih root permissions:

```
tex eforms.ins
tex dljslib.ins
tex insdljs.ins
tex taborder.ins
tex acrotex.ins
```

And then run finally `sudo texhash`.